# Local Directive Vuejs arguments are undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having issues trying to wireup a directive in Vue.js based on the example online.

```
<div id="hook-arguments-example" v-demo:foo.a.b="message"></div>
```

Here is the directive inline with the main Vue App

```
    const v = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'hello!'
         },
        directives: {
            demo: {
                update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                    console.log(el);
                    console.log(binding);
                    console.log(vnode);
                    var s = JSON.stringify
                    el.innerHTML =
                        'name: ' + s(binding.name) + '<br>' +
                        'value: ' + s(binding.value) + '<br>' +
                        'expression: ' + s(binding.expression) + '<br>' +
                        'argument: ' + s(binding.arg) + '<br>' +
                        'modifiers: ' + s(binding.modifiers) + '<br>' +
                        'vnode keys: ' + Object.keys(vnode).join(', ')
                }
            }
        }
   })
```

When I run this, whether it is using bind or update hook, `el`,`binding`,`vnode` are all undefined? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to work fine https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zEwOvd?editors=1010

Comment: This is bizarre, if I copy that code from that pen, it does not work. Does the div need to be visible? Like if I have v-if that shows it right before I call directive does that break it?

Comment: What version of Vue are you using? Visibility is not an issue (the pen is updated with the ability to toggle it).

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>

Comment: Well, that is Vue 1. The pen is Vue 2. Are you intentionally using Vue 1?

Comment: Nope I must have just grabbed the wrong url... However it looks like v-if no longer works after that

Comment: That sounds like a different issue.

Comment: totally is... was working fine with 1, wonder what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question code works correctly with Vue 2. OP was using Vue 1 unintentionally.

```js
console.clear()

function onLifecycle(el, binding, vnode) {
  var s = JSON.stringify
  el.innerHTML =
    'name: ' + s(binding.name) + '<br>' +
    'value: ' + s(binding.value) + '<br>' +
    'expression: ' + s(binding.expression) + '<br>' +
    'argument: ' + s(binding.arg) + '<br>' +
    'modifiers: ' + s(binding.modifiers) + '<br>' +
    'vnode keys: ' + Object.keys(vnode).join(', ')
}

const v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'hello!',
    visible: false
  },
  directives: {
    demo: {
      bind: onLifecycle ,
      update: onLifecycle
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div  v-if="visible">
    <div id="hook-arguments-example" v-demo:foo.a.b="message"></div>
  </div>
  <button @click="message='world'">Update Message</button>
  <button @click="visible=!visible">Toggle Visible</button>
</div>
```